# Run processes in parallel while capturing video with opencv

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm using opencv to capture a video from my webcam. Every 5 seconds, I'm processing a single frame / an image which can take some seconds. So far everything works. But whenever a frame is processed the entire video is freezing for a couple of seconds (Until the process is finished). I'm trying to get rid of it by using Threading. Here is what I did so far:

Inside the while loop which is capturing the video:

```
    while True:
        ret, image = cap.read()

        if next_time <= datetime.now():

            content_type = 'image/jpeg'
            headers = {'content-type': content_type}
            _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            future = asyncio.ensure_future(self.async_faces(img_encoded, headers))
            loop.run_until_complete(future)

            next_time += period
            ...

        cv2.imshow('img', image)
```

Here are the methods:

```
async def async_faces(self, img, headers):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        tasks = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor,
                self.face_detection,
                *(img, headers)  # Allows us to pass in multiple arguments to `fetch`
            )
        ]

        for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            pass

def face_detection(self, img, headers):
    try:
        response = requests.post(self.url, data=img.tostring(), headers=headers)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        ...

    ...
```

But unfortunately it's not working.

**EDIT 1**

In the following I add what the whole thing is supposed to do.

Originally, the function looked like:

```
import requests
import cv2
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def face_recognition(self):

    # Start camera
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)

    emotional_states = []
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    period = timedelta(seconds=self.time_period)
    next_time = datetime.now() + period

    cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty('img', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

    while True:
        ret, image = cap.read()

        if next_time <= datetime.now():

            # Prepare headers for http request
            content_type = 'image/jpeg'
            headers = {'content-type': content_type}
            _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)

            try:
                # Send http request with image and receive response
                response = requests.post(self.url, data=img_encoded.tostring(), headers=headers)
                emotional_states = response.json().get("emotions")
                face_locations = response.json().get("locations")
            except Exception as e:
                emotional_states = []
                face_locations = []
                print(e)

            next_time += period

        for i in range(0, len(emotional_states)):
            emotion = emotional_states[i]
            face_location = face_locations[i]
            cv2.putText(image, emotion, (int(face_location[0]), int(face_location[1])),
                        font, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('img', image)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cap.release()
            break
        if k == ord('a'):
            cv2.resizeWindow('img', 700,700)
```

I use the above method to film myself. This film will be shown live on my screen. Further, every 5 seconds one frame is send to an API where the image is processed in such a way that the emotion of the person in the image is returned. This emotion is displayed on my screen, next to myself. The problem is, that the live video is freezing for a couple of seconds until the emotion is returned from the API.

My OS is Ubuntu.

**EDIT 2**

The API is running locally. I created a Flask App and the following method is receiving the request:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import numpy as np
import cv2
import json

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def facial_emotion_recognition():

    # Convert string of image data to uint8
    nparr = np.fromstring(request.data, np.uint8)
    # Decode image
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Analyse the image
    emotional_state, face_locations = emotionDetection.analyze_facial_emotions(img)

    json_dump = json.dumps({'emotions': emotional_state, 'locations': face_locations}, cls=NumpyEncoder)

    return Response(json_dump, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Threading in python is a bit strangely named. If you spawn threads via the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, those threads are executed in the same process. You are still handicapped by the Global Interpreter Lock. Using threads in python only makes sense when you are IO-bottlenecked and the CPU is essentially sitting idle waiting for IO. That is most likely why your program hangs while it is processing the image (you are CPU bottlenecked, not IO bottlenecked). There's the `ProcessPoolExecutor` that spawns separate processes, but I'm afraid that might not work with the asyncio event loop stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I don't have any other ideas. My head is telling me that it can't be that complicated. But obviously it is ..

Comment: I'm not too experienced with this stuff either. Could you separate the processes by running a separate python process that looks for the image in a certain folder on your file system? And the first process writes images to that folder periodically? That way, your first process shouldn't lock up when the second process uses lots of CPU, the downside may be that you lose a bit of performance through IO operations.

Comment: I'm missing the bigger picture here. Why are you JPEG-encoding the image? Where are you sending it? How can you run `imshow()` with no `waitKey()`? What machine and OS are you running on? Why have you removed all the `import` statements so no-one else can run it? What is the whole thing supposed to do?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I thought that all the stuff you mentioned is not important to the question. However, I added some more information and details. Thanks

Comment: Where are you sending the image to? I can't see the URL. What causes the freezing? Does it freeze while waiting for the result from the URL?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry for the circumstances. I added more information. Further, I'm sure that the freezing is caused by waiting for the results from the URL.